# Fetch and display new contents when user click on each list item [React]

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-router

First, I want to load a JSON from my server; it will contain a list of objects. Then, I need to render these objects like a list. When a list item is clicked, the user should be redirected to a page that shows information about the clicked item. That information displayed should be fetched from another API call to my server.

Can someone guide me, please?

```
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    users: [],
    error: null
  };

  fetchUsers() {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/blog/view`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          users: data,
          isLoading: false,
        })
      )
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUsers();
  }
  render() {
    const { isLoading, users, error } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1  style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>My Blog</h1>
        {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : null}
        {!isLoading ? (
          users.map(user => {
            const { _id, title, details,date } = user;

            return (

                <div className='blog'>

              <div key={_id}>
                <p>Name: {title}</p>
                <p>Email Address: {details}</p>
                <p >Email Address: {date}</p>
                <hr className='banner-text hr' />
              </div>
              </div>
            );
          })
        ) : (
          <h3>Loading...</h3>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Moshe and welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried using For loop?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Amir how can I add for every Json object a separate page when I click on the is

Comment: The whole idea of react, is to separate rendering (view) from data (model). So based on this philosophy, you can create a component that takes an object in its `props` and renders its page. Then you can use an `onClick` event (on the list items or where ever you are displaying your objects) and render that particular page in place of current page. You can even use react-router to redirect to local routes

Comment: @Moshe Let me see if I understand your question:
You want to first load a json from somewhere, that contains a list of objects. Then you need to render these objects like a list (as you said, like blog entries). Then you want that clicking on each of these objects, redirect you to a page that shows information about that clicked object. And this information also comes from an api call (a remote server). Is this your question?

Comment: @Amir YES ACTUALLY CAN YOU GUIDE ME PLEASE

Comment: OK, hold on, I'm writing a sample code for you

Comment: Checkout my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample project to demonstrate how you can use react and react-router together.

We first fetch a list of users from some api, and then display them as a list.
Using react-router, we add a link to each item so that when it's clicked, the page url changes

**but page wont reload! these are internal links**

Then again using react-router, we display different contents based on the url.
And at last, we have a `UserPage` component that when mounted, fetches the data for the specific user page and renders it.

Hope it is clear enough

---

This is a very good [tutorial on react-router](https://youtu.be/cKnc8gXn80Q)

And this is the [official react tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)

I strongly recommend that you take a look at them

---

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import User from "./User"
import UserPage from "./UserPage"

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      isLoading: false
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true })
    fetch('https://your/api/url')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({
            users: response,
            isLoading: false
          })
        })
  }

  render() {
    let content;
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      content = <h1>Loading...</h1>
    } else if (this.state.users.length > 0) {
      content = this.state.users.map(u =>
          <Link to={`/users/${u._id}`}>
            <User key={u._id} user={u} />
          </Link>
          )
    } else {
      content = <h4>No users found!</h4>
    }
    return (
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Route path="/users/:_id" component={UserPage}/>
            <Route exact={true} path="/" render={() => content}/>
          </div>
        </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**User.js**

```
import React from 'react'

function User(props) {
    const {title, details, date} = props.user;
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Name: {title}</p>
            <p>Email Address: {details}</p>
            <p>Email Address: {date}</p>
            <hr className='banner-text hr' />
        </div>
    )
}

export default User
```

**UserPage.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class UserPage extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
            data: '',
            id: this.props.match.params._id
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true })
        fetch(`https://your/api/url/for/user/${this.state.id}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    data: response,
                    isLoading: false
                })
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            this.state.isLoading ?
                (<h1>Loading page of user {this.state.id}...</h1>)
                :
                (
                    <div>
                        <p>{this.state.data}</p>
                    </div>
                )
    )
    }
}

export default UserPage
```